# AMD GPU Rendering R7 Series

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have an AMD Radeon R7 200 series in my desktop, and was wondering if it was compatible for OpenCL GPU rendering in Blender? I have researched and researched but have been unable to have my question answered. Thanks!

Comment: I would say a very cautious yes... if you do a search for AMD GPUs in this site you'll soon discover that the support is not complete and there are a few issues with incompatible drivers. Proceed with caution if you are looking into purchasing an  ATI GPU

Answer (score 2):

My previous card was a R7 200 series, my actual card is a R9 200 series. While both cards actually seem to work with Blender, there are two major drawbacks.

1. The actual driver is faulty and renders "TV stripes" into your image (see https://community.amd.com/thread/198677)
2. Blender's development team (like many others) sadly seems to focus on NVIDIA, thus AMD GPU (OpenCL) rendering is not that optimized than NVIDIA's (CUDA) (see https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Blender-Slow-OpenCL-AMDGPU)

Even with the "good" drivers I haven't experienced much faster rendering.

**Update: I just tested the current driver hotfix 16.8.1 under Windows 7. They seem to work significantly faster and also the "TV stripes" seem to be gone. Linux test might follow by the end of the week.**

Comment: Any update on this? AMD worked on Cycles together with Blender devs. So does it work on Linux now?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes.

According to [the Blender wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL), OpenCL is in fact supported for all six Radeon R7 200-series card models that appear on [the Radeon Rx 200 series Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Radeon_Rx_200_series).

You will need to make sure you have up to date drivers installed and the GPU selected as the compute device in the settings of Blender, system tab.

Answer (score 0):

Under the "System" tab in Blender Preferences, check the compute device setting. If OpenCL is listed, change the option from none to that, and select the GPU you would like to render with.

[image: GPU Rendering]

If no device is listed, your GPU may not be compatible, or is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: yes, but from personal experience, OpenCL integration in Blender is slow and lacking. Primary focus is on CUDA(Nvidia), so OpenCL is lacking key features(SSS, Branched Path, Volume, etc.) Last time I used it(R5 card here), it had no support for HDR textures, but that's probably fixed now. See [the Blender manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/features.html) for more details.